# How to Calculate Azure Virtual Machine Up hours?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have created virtual machine on azure and deployed one website on Virtual Machine IIS server. Now I want to calculate hours of Virtual Machine were up including storage and backup? How to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"? Do you want to measure the uptime or predict it or something else?

Comment: I want to see virtual machine up(running) hours.

Comment: there's no direct metric available for the uptime. You might want to calculate using the status (change of state) of VMs. refer here: https://faultbucket.ca/2019/05/get-azure-vm-uptime-sorta/